# Best way to run a web server on a pi zero w that changes the pattern of an led strip on the same pi?

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

So basically I am trying to build a led project with a raspberry pi zero w. I have gotten the led python scripts working inside my flask web project. But i would like to be able to change the patterns on the led strips just with a button click on the web page that is generated by the pi. Im currently using flask to run the web server and updates send to it. Im also using execnet to run the pattern methods from a python 2 file as the NeoPixel library is only in python 2 and not 3.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import execnet
CURRENT_PATTERN = "No Pattern Running"
app = Flask(__name__)
def callPython2(Version, Module, Function, Args):
    gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % Version)
    channel = gw.remote_exec("""
        from %s import %s as the_function
        channel.send(the_function(*channel.receive()))
    """ % (Module, Function))
    channel.send(Args)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    CURRENT_PATTERN = 'BootUp'
    callPython2("2.7", "lakeboot", "startUp", "")
    templateData = {
        'title' : 'LED Pattern Status',
        'pattern' : CURRENT_PATTERN,
    }
    return render_templates("index.html', **templateData)

@app.route("/<patternName>/<action>")
def action(patternName, action):
    if action == 'stop':
        CURRENT_PATTERN = 'No Pattern Running"
        callPython2("2.7", "lakeboot", "turnOff", "")
    if patternName == 'TheaterChase':
        CURRENT_PATTERN = 'Theater Chase'
        callPython2("2.7", "lakeboot", "runTheater", "")
    #More Pattern calls like above
    templateData = {
        'title' : "LED Pattern Status',
        'pattern' : CURRENT_PATTERN,
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)`
```

This is what my webPage.py file looks like. The pattern change calls work but then it only does one iteration of the selected pattern, but i would like it to loop until told to stop or a new pattern is selected.

P.S. Sorry if the format is bad Have never posted on here before and also only been working with python for a few months.

EDIT:
Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>LED Status</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='../static/style.css'/>
   </head>

   <body>
                <h2> Status </h2>
                <h3> Current Pattern ==>  {{ pattern  }}</h3>
                <br>
                <h2> Commands </h2>
                <h3>
                        Run Bootup ==>
                        <a href="/bootup/start" class="button">TURN ON</a>
                        <a href="/bootup/stop" class="button">TURN OFF</a>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                        Run Theater Chase ==>
                        <a href="/TheaterChase/start" class="button">TURN ON</a>
                        <a href="/TheaterChase/stop"class="button">TURN OFF</a>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                        Run Pattern Three ==>
                        <a href="/ledGrn/start" class="button">TURN ON</a>
                </h3>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is very vague... you have some unspecified type of LEDs on a Raspberry Pi and you want to change them in some unspecified way when a user clicks some unspecified button on an unspecified website. That's a poor brief. Pressing the button could open a magnet that drops a hammer on your LEDs - that would change them.

Comment: Yeah sorry posted by mistake before all content was placed. Should all be there now. The quick notes are, Click a button on the web page, stop the old animation/pattern, then start the new animation or pattern based off the button pressed.

Comment: can you also post your index.html template?

Comment: Should be posted now

Comment: Your code is a little bit repetitive, but I don't understand what you means " it only does one iteration of the selected pattern"? as long as you clicking "turn on" and "turn off" of each patterns, it will works accordingly.

Comment: So basicly how its set up on the LED side, is that a function has all the steps to run an animation i.e set all leds to green wait 10ms then change them all to red. So by one iteration i mean that the function is only called once. Rather than x amount of times. i have tried to make these functions infinite but then have found no way of stopping them when wanting to change a animation. These animations could possibly be running for hours and not just a few times so its not best to hard code in a value for how many times to run.

Comment: So you means only the `/` route work, but `/<patternName>/<action>/` route not working?

Comment: Both directories work, I can click the buttons to change the animation, but they do not run forever. Or they do run forever and i have no way of stopping the last function call to start another.

Comment: Well, you should get an error on your route action(), because you didn't pass in the arguments as `def action(patternName, action):`.

Comment: No Errors are thrown. Everything runs fine until i try to stop an old python script and use another. I can't get them to stop so i end up running two led patterns at the same time resulting in just flashing lights.

Comment: Check "Variable Rules" section of the Flask Quickstart [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/), and check your action() function again.

Comment: Oh my mistake sorry. Since im working in a putty terminal its rather difficult to just copy and paste so i wrote out the code while looking at the terminal. I do have the variables set correctly and i will update the code in the post. Also i have found a work around for what i was looking for. Thanks for your time gents!

Answer (score 0):

One unusual, but not entirely crazy, approach is to run Flask in a thread, with the main thread controlling the LEDs. The LED side and the Flask side would communicate through a shared data structure, which you should arrange to lock if you're doing anything more complicated than doing an atomic assign to it.

The basic flow is:

1. Create the share state holder
2. Inject it into a Flask config
3. Start the Flask app in a thread
4. Do your foreground thing (control LEDs in this case) periodically examining the shared state holder for a new setting/command.
5. Flask handlers interrogate/set via the shared state holder.

For anything more than a single state value, the state holder will want to lock access internally.

I have a working example that controls a camera [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/lapse/blob/master/lapse.py#L30).

The key parts, edited down a bit are

```
def webserver(control):
    app.config['CONTROL'] = control
    # It isn't safe to use the reloader in a thread
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_reloader=False)

control = Control()
ui_thread = threading.Thread(target=webserver, args=(control,))
ui_thread.start()

while control.running():
    # control the LEDs, periodically interrogating control
```

From the Flask side,

```
@app.route('/command', methods=['POST'])
def command():
    control = app.config['CONTROL']
    control.command(request.form.get('command'))
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: That's sounds way overkill for such a simple application. In fact personally I think even using Flask is overkill. I just use [web socket](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/) which is part of standard library of python for a simple http server.

Comment: [How to control Raspberry Pi GPIO via http web server](http://localhost/e-tinkers/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/).

Comment: @hcheung That URL isn't complete

Comment: The code is available at my [github](https://github.com/e-tinkers/simple_httpserver) as well.

Comment: @hcheung That's a nice, lightweight, single-threaded web server. It'll turn LEDs on and off, but it won't run animations. For that you'll need another thread or process.